# How can I make a method that creates a Line from one point to another using Buttons as points?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to make a button that when it is pressed, creates a line from the position of one button, to the position of another button that I pressed.

For example, I want to make a line between these two black buttons called Button1 and Button2:

[image: Button1 To Button2]

What I've tried so far:

```
    public void createLine(ActionEvent event) {
        Line line1 = new Line();
        line1.setStartX(Button1.getLayoutX());
        line1.setStartY(Button1.getLayoutY());
        line1.setEndX(Button2.getLayoutX());
        line1.setEndY(Button2.getLayoutY());
    }
```

This seems to not create any line at all when I press the button.

Comment: Do you add the line to the scene graph at any point?

Comment: You are going to have to keep up with the first and second clicks. Store the first click and store the second click. Draw the line and reset back to the first click.

Comment: @James_D I want to add the line to the same AnchorPane group that the Buttons are and I want that line to connect the first point which is one button and the other point which is another button, check my image for an example, I also edited the question, hope it helps

Comment: @Sedrick How can I do that? Can you show me some example code?

Comment: So just add the code to add the line to the anchor pane. It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Two important things here.

1. Make sure you have access to the `Buttons` locations when needed.
2. Keep track of if the first or second `Button` is being pressed.

This code is not complete! It only demos the OP's question. Nothing more. Comments in the code.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application
{

    ButtonLocation buttonLocation;//Keeps up with location of the first button.
    Pane pane;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {

        Button btn1 = new Button("1");
        Button btn2 = new Button("2");
        Button btn3 = new Button("3");
        btn1.setOnAction(btnActionEventHandler);
        btn2.setOnAction(btnActionEventHandler);
        btn3.setOnAction(btnActionEventHandler);
        btn1.setLayoutX(20);
        btn1.setLayoutY(20);
        btn2.setLayoutX(100);
        btn2.setLayoutY(20);
        btn3.setLayoutX(100);
        btn3.setLayoutY(100);
        
        pane = new Pane(btn1, btn2, btn3);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(pane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    int counter = 0;// Used to determine if the first or second button is pressed. This with modulo.
    final EventHandler<ActionEvent> btnActionEventHandler = (final ActionEvent event) -> {
        Button tempButton = (Button)event.getSource();
        
        switch (counter % 2) {
            case 0 -> {
                System.out.println("First button pressed");
                buttonLocation = new ButtonLocation(tempButton.getLayoutX(), tempButton.getLayoutY());//Save the location of the first button pressed.
                
                counter++;
            }
            case 1 -> {
                System.out.println("Second button pressed!");
                Line line = new Line(buttonLocation.buttonOneLocationX(), buttonLocation.buttonOneLocationY(), tempButton.getLayoutX(), tempButton.getLayoutY());//create line from first button press and second button press.
                pane.getChildren().add(line);//Add the line to the pane
                
                counter++;
            }
        }
    };

    public record ButtonLocation(double buttonOneLocationX, double buttonOneLocationY){ }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]